# CALCULAR PRIMA DE SERVICIOS ODOO 12

Tags: python, odoo

Actualmente estoy implementando el calculo y la gestión de nomina en Odoo 12, y estoy intentando calcular la prima de servicios, es la que el estado otorga al empleado cada semestre del año.
por lo cual necesito saber cuantos días ha trabajado el empleado para poder aplicar la expresión
he intentado lo siguiente

`result = contract.wage + contract.rodamiento * 180/360`  ------ esta funciona perfecto, porque le defino la cantidad de días que trabajo en este caso 180
lo que requiero es saber en que variable se almacena el tiempo laborado del empleado sean 20, 30 o mas días,

lo otro que intente es calculando la tabla  **hr_attendance** que cuente los días de acuerdo a la marcación. y guardando el resultado en la tabla **hr_contract** para luego llamarlo en la expresión Python de la siguiente manera

```
result = contract.wage + contract.rodamiento * contract.work_time/360
```

pero me genera error. quisiera saber de que otra manera puedo hacerlo??

Comment: *pero me genera error* -> A lo mejor si nos dices ***qué error***, alguien podría ayudarte. Porque no vamos a ponernos a hacer todo el proyecto entero en odoo solo para ver qué error te da! Recuerda que siempre es muy importante poner toda la información relacionada a los errores y el código empleado cuando no se puede ofrecer un [mre]. Errores, código involucrado, tablas... todo ayudará a que podamos encontrar una solución.

Comment: @Benito-B Si, tienes razon voy a adjuntar el error que me genera. gracias lo tendre mas en cuenta